# My computer crashes at random due to, WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124). i'm unable to identify what exactly is the cause

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure, bsod

My PC will blue or black screen at random, especially when playing a game, some games cause the BSOD quicker than others.

I recently upgraded my CPU, GPU and ram. I have ran memory tests for the ram which have found no issues. My GPU is on latest drivers as well as all my other system drivers.

Here's the dump from the most recent crash: https://pastebin.com/Ea2BKNka

I understand its a hardware issue, potentially with my CPU or motherboard. its highly likely to be the motherboard as it is an old model. My motherboard is: https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-A320M-S2H-rev-1x#kf

I have updated to the latest BIOS that i can.

Here is my system information: https://pastebin.com/xwCsxdLf

Comment: Have you done any BIOS tweaks, specifically with CPU "performance"

Answer (score 1):

Consider the error you post states: "FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x124_0_**AuthenticAMD**_PROCESSOR_CACHE_IMAGE_AuthenticAMD.sys". For some reason, your motherboard does not identify the new CPU you just replaced as an authentic AMD device.

This issue is discussed at Appuals.com, [*How to Fix AuthenticAMD.sys BSOD on Windows 10/11*](https://appuals.com/authenticamd-sys-bsod-windows/)

Some possible causes and remedies:

- The CPU is newer than the BIOS. Though you've updated the BIOS, that might not *yet* be a version compatible with the CPU.
- Newer Windows and AMD drivers are needed. In particular, update *video* drivers that the new CPU and/or GPU use. Perform normal Windows Update. Use [System File Checker (SFC) and Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e) utilities to look for and repair outdated or bad system files, as well. Search the PC, CPU and GPU sites for newer drivers.
- Some users find the issue is less common with [Fast Startup](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup) disabled.
- The CPU is incompatible with the motherboard, and there is *no* version of BIOS that can recognize it. oops
- Least likely, the CPU might not be authentic chip. Though I know there are incidents of fake flash RAM, I've not heard of counterfeit CPU's.

Comment: I did most of the fixes you gave. I have updated all drivers, disabled fast startup and have ran both SFC and DSIM. this seems to have fixed the crashing issue, i have tested with many games and my PC runs with no issues. However i have suddenly noticed a big increase in load times for boot and loading applications. Could this be with my SSD?

Answer (score 0):

As you note, WHEA errors are normally hardware.

Try updating all drivers you can in addition to the BIOS which you did.

Going forward, unfortunately, you have to test and replace parts, which can be expensive.

So I would take it to a local shop that can identify the failing part. I think this is the most practical way forward.

> its highly likely to be the motherboard as it is an old model.

You have an old motherboard with some newer components.  This may or may not be your issue.

Taking this and the motherboard age into account, the other approach may be to consider replacing the computer.